# Python: 4 for loops

Tags: python

I have been trying to calculate aa by using dell, x, y and r, but i cannot find where my misteke is. I want to obtain **( xx + yy ) / yy + rr + d** as 1 x 10 vector.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 

a = 2 
dell = np.linspace(20, 40, num=10) 

x = np.linspace(10, 10, num=10) 
y = np.linspace(10, 10, num=10) 
r = np.linspace(-3,5, num=10)
  
for d in dell:
     for xx in x:
         for yy in y:
             for rr in r:
                 aa = a * ( xx + yy ) / yy + rr + d
```

Comment: you are assigning aa in each for step, but forgeting it in the next one.

Comment: And most importantly, by chaining the loops like this, the code performs 10**4 operations (all combinations), very far from the expected linear 10 operations

Answer (score 4):

**Don't use loops!**

Numpy is designed to work with vectorial operations:

```
(x + y) / y + r + dell
```

output:

```
array([19.        , 22.11111111, 25.22222222, 28.33333333, 31.44444444,
       34.55555556, 37.66666667, 40.77777778, 43.88888889, 47.        ])
```

##### how to perform the calculation with a loop (which is NOT a good idea):

You only need a single loop:

```py
out = np.zeros(10)
for i in range(len(out)):
    out[i] = (x[i] + y[i]) / y[i] + r[i] + dell[i]
```

But again, this is **slower** and **less explicit**, you might just use python lists here and don't bother with numpy.